# Retrieve Email Body Text Using imaplib

Tags: python, imaplib

I'm trying to ensure that I retrieve all of the body text (no matter what format the email is in) from a certain email address.  The connection details are omitted in this example (imaplib_connect) since all seems to work, but I don't think the below is sufficient for all email bodies.  Any improvement recommendations? I'm writing each email's body to a file.

```
import imaplib
import imaplib_connect
import uuid
import ConfigParser
import os
import email

c = imaplib_connect.open_connection()
try:
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.read([os.path.expanduser('~/reader.config')])
    fromAddress = config.get('account', 'fromAddress')
    typ, data = c.select('INBOX')
    typ, data = c.search(None, '(FROM "' + fromAddress + '")')
    print "Processing..."
    for num in data[0].split():
        typ, data = c.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        rawMessage = data[0][1]
        emailMessage = email.message_from_string(rawMessage)
        maintype = emailMessage.get_content_maintype()
        fileName = uuid.uuid4().hex
        if maintype == 'multipart':
             for part in emailMessage.get_payload():
                 if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text':
                    with open(fileName + ".txt", "wb") as fo:
                         fo.write(part.get_payload())
                 elif maintype == 'text':
                    with open(fileName + ".txt", "wb") as fo:
                         fo.write(part.get_payload())
finally:
    try:
        c.close()
    except:
        pass
    c.logout()
```